# .NET Core BackgroudService DI Scope null

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-core, background-process

I have a .NET backgroud service

```
public class Worker : BackgroundService
    {
        private readonly ILogger<Worker> _logger;
        private readonly ConvertService _convert;

        public Worker(ILogger<Worker> logger, ConvertService convert)
        {
            _logger = logger;
            _convert = convert;
        }

        protected override async Task ExecuteAsync(CancellationToken stoppingToken)
        {
            while (!stoppingToken.IsCancellationRequested)
            {
                await _convert.GetXML();
                await Task.Delay(TimeSpan.FromHours(12), stoppingToken);
            }
        }
    }
```

Program.cs

```
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore;
using P1_APT_SUB;
using P1_APT_SUB.BusService;
using P1_APT_SUB.Persistence;


IHost host = Host.CreateDefaultBuilder(args)
    
    .UseWindowsService(options =>
    {
        options.ServiceName = "APT";
    })
    .ConfigureServices((context,services) =>
    {
        services.AddHttpClient("auth", httpClient =>
        {
          
          
        });
        services.AddHttpClient("ODM", httpClient =>
        {
            
        });
        services.AddTransient<ConvertService>();
        services.AddTransient<BusServiceClass>();
        services.AddHostedService<Worker>();
        services.AddDbContext<DataContext>(
                 options =>
                 {
                     options.UseSqlServer();
                 });
    })
    .Build();

await host.RunAsync();
```

ConvertService.cs

Here is create scope and pass that to method like `GetST()` and httpCLient is ok

```
using Newtonsoft.Json.Linq;
using System.Xml.Linq;
using P1_APT_SUB.BusService;
using P1_APT_SUB.Persistence;
using P1_APT_SUB.Entities;

namespace P1_APT_SUB
{


    public class ConvertService
    {
        private readonly IHttpClientFactory? _httpClientFactory;
        private readonly IConfiguration? _config;
        private readonly DataContext _dataContext;
    
        private readonly BusServiceClass _busService;
        static public string? sites;
        

        public ConvertService(IConfiguration config, IServiceScopeFactory factory)
        {

            _httpClientFactory = factory.CreateScope().ServiceProvider.GetRequiredService<IHttpClientFactory>();
            _config = config;
            _dataContext = factory.CreateScope().ServiceProvider.GetRequiredService<DataContext>();
            _busService = factory.CreateScope().ServiceProvider.GetRequiredService<BusServiceClass>();
        }
        public ConvertService()
        {

        }
    
        public async Task GetXML()
        {
            var data = await new Domains().GetST(_httpClientFactory, _config);
            sites = await new Domains().GetSD(_httpClientFactory, _config);
       
        }

    }}
}
```

Domains.cs

```
using Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration;
using Newtonsoft.Json.Linq;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Net.Http;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace P1_APT_SUB
{
    public class Domains
    {
        public string subjects;
        public string sites;
        private readonly IHttpClientFactory _httpClientFactory;

      

        public async Task<string> GetST(IHttpClientFactory _httpClientFactory, IConfiguration _config)
        {
            
                var accessToken = await Authorization.GetAccessToken(_httpClientFactory);

                var httpClient = _httpClientFactory.CreateClient("ODM");
                httpClient.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("X-ACCESS-TOKEN", accessToken);

                var httpResponseMessage = await httpClient.GetAsync();
                if (httpResponseMessage.IsSuccessStatusCode)
                {
                    var contentStream =
                       await httpResponseMessage.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
                subjects = contentStream;
                 
                }
                return subjects;
            
           
           
        }
        public async Task<string> GetSD(IHttpClientFactory _httpClientFactory, IConfiguration _config)
        {
            
            
                var accessToken = await Authorization.GetAccessToken(_httpClientFactory);

                var httpClient = _httpClientFactory.CreateClient("ODM");
                httpClient.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("X-ACCESS-TOKEN", accessToken);

                var httpResponseMessage = await httpClient.GetAsync();
                if (httpResponseMessage.IsSuccessStatusCode)
                {
                    var contentssStream =
                       await httpResponseMessage.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();

                sites = contentssStream;

                }
                return sites;
           
           
        }
       

    }
}
```

But when i want to DI/create scope directly in `Domains` like below it httpCLient is null. It is related that BackgroundService is singleton i think so DI?

```
using Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration;
using Newtonsoft.Json.Linq;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Net.Http;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace P1_APT_SUB
{
    public class Domains
    {
        public string subjects;
    
        private readonly IHttpClientFactory _httpClientFactory;

        public Domains(IServiceScopeFactory factory)
        {
            this.subjects = subjects;
            this.sites = sites;
           _httpClientFactory = factory.CreateScope().ServiceProvider.GetRequiredService<IHttpClientFactory>();
        }

        public Domains()
        {
        }

        public async Task<string> GetSubjects(IConfiguration _config)
        {
            
                var accessToken = await Authorization.GetAccessToken(**_httpClientFactory**);

                var httpClient = _httpClientFactory.CreateClient("ODM");
                httpClient.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("X-ACCESS-TOKEN", accessToken);

                var httpResponseMessage = await httpClient.GetAsync();
                if (httpResponseMessage.IsSuccessStatusCode)
                {
                    var contentStream =
                       await httpResponseMessage.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
                subjects = contentStream;
                 
                }
                return subjects;
            
           
           
        }
       
       

    }
}
```

**EDIT**

About DataContext being singleton i think this will do the job? as `using` will call `Dispose()`? sometimes it does not

`await using var scope = _factory.CreateAsyncScope(); var context = scope.ServiceProvider.GetRequiredService<DataContext>(); List<Subject>? currentData = context.Subjects.ToList();`

---

Added Domains as service and DI it into ConvertService

```
 services.AddTransient<Domains>();
```

---

```
 public ConvertService(IConfiguration config, IServiceScopeFactory factory, Domains domains)
        {

            _httpClientFactory = factory.CreateScope().ServiceProvider.GetRequiredService<IHttpClientFactory>();
            _config = config;
            _domains = domains;
            _factory = factory;
         
            _busService = factory.CreateScope().ServiceProvider.GetRequiredService<BusServiceClass>();
        }
```

now i can DI IServiceScopeFactory in `Domains` without passing it from Convert

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue is n your constructor: I assumed the `Domains` object will created by DI, but you create it manually by using the default constructor:

```
public Domains(IServiceScopeFactory factory)
{
    this.subjects = subjects;
    this.sites = sites;
    _httpClientFactory = factory.CreateScope().ServiceProvider.GetRequiredService<IHttpClientFactory>();
}

public Domains()
{
}
```

When you call create the `Domains` instance with `new Domains()` all members will be `null` since the parameterless constructor does nothing.

To fix this you have to call the `Domains(IServiceScopeFactory)` constructor.

The easiest way would be to store the `IServiceScopeFactory` instance in `ConverService` in a field and pass that to the constructor:

```
var data = await new Domains(_factory).GetST(_httpClientFactory, _config);
sites = await new Domains(_factory).GetSD(_httpClientFactory, _config);
```

However, please take a look at the scopes as well, as your code currently will make your `DataContext` basically a singelton because of the way you create the instance.

EDIT: Original, but wrong answer:
You should not create the scopes in the constructor of a singleton.

Think of the scope as the owner of its created services. Once the scope gets
disposed all disposable services created by the scope get disposed as well.

In your constructors you create temporary scopes that might be disposed by GC before you can use your services.

What you should do instead is to inject `IServiceScopeFactory` in your constructor and create and dispose your service scope as needed:

```
// Create new scope and dispose after use
using var scope = _serviceScopeFactory.CreateScope();

// Resolve instances
var service = scope.ServiceProvider.GetRequiredService<TService>();
```

For more guidelines take look at https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/extensions/dependency-injection-guidelines

Comment: public Domains(IServiceScopeFactory factory)
        {
            this.subjects = subjects;
            this.sites = sites;
           _httpClientFactory = factory.CreateScope().ServiceProvider.GetRequiredService<IHttpClientFactory>();
        }

Comment: I have that scope in constructor but usage is wrong? Why in covnertservice IT works but not in domain even if i do it by constructor

Comment: My first intuition was wrong. The problem is the default constructor of `Domains`.  However you should still review your usage of DI scopes in your projects, as it might lead to problems.

Comment: i already pass this factory here  var data = await new Domains().GetST(_httpClientFactory, _config);
            sites = await new Domains().GetSD(_httpClientFactory, _config);  you can find it above but this is scope? and is wrong? the thing is I want DI not props drilling down.

Comment: It is about the `new Domains()` where you should call `new Domains(serviceScopeFactory)`. If you want to create `Domain` via DI then make it a dependency and pass it to `ConvertService` in the constructor rather than creating instances manually with  `new`.

Comment: Please check my updated question when i add Domains as DI

Comment: Sorry. I am running out of Ideas. Could you please create a [Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)? The Error message and stack trace would also help.
From what I see in the provided code there are also some fields uninitialized (like `subjects`or `sites` in the `Domains` class). This could also be a cause.

Comment: it works no errors

Comment: when i register Domains as service and DI it into CovnertService it is ok no errors. Also i DI IServiceScopeFactory factory into Domains and other servicies and using this [ await using var scope = _factory.CreateAsyncScope();
            var _httpClientFactory = scope.ServiceProvider.GetRequiredService<IHttpClientFactory>();] to mange scope

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/250002/discussion-between-exc-and-christian-held).